# Make: Auto dependency generation

Tags: makefile

i have one doubt on auto dependency file generation with Make.
Here i have makefile with below content.

```
DEPSALL := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $(TGTFILES)/*.c)))
-include $(DEPSALL)
$(TGTFILES)/%.o: $(TGTFILES)/%.c
     mkdir -p $(@D)
     $(CC64) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $@)) -o $(@) -c $(CFLAGS64) $<
...
...
```

I am new to GNUmake and trying to do some experiment. I know that above -M* flags are used to create auto dependency files "*.d" with target and dependencies for each obj file. 
Here, while compiling the code i just commented out first two lines and did not see any difference while compiling the code. Not sure how those lines effect in my compilation.

Is it really necessary to have those two lines in my makefile? Without 'include' directive (-include $(DEPSALL)) its working fine.

Comment: If you ran the same commands before and the files were already generated, that would work (but eventually the files will contain out-of-date information). The `-include` with a minus will silently ignore any missing files. The purpose of a dependency is to tell Make when to remake something; without the dependency file, Make will consider `fnord.c` up to date when you changed `fnord.h` even though they have a dependency.

Comment: Hi,I havent ran any commands before.I ran for the first time without those two lines, Dependency files got created and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have fully built your code, so when you run `make` nothing happens because everything is up to date.

Now suppose one of your source files `foo.c` includes a header file `bar.h`.  You edit the header file `bar.h` but you don't edit the source file `foo.c`.  For the purposes of this experiment you can use `touch bar.h` to simulate editing.

Now if you comment out the first two lines above, when you run `make` it will say nothing needs to be done and not recompile anything, even though a header file was changed.  If you don't comment out the first two lines above, when you run `make` it will realize that the header was changed and recompile the source file.

*That* is what those two lines and all the `-MT` etc. options are for.

Comment: Thanks for your Explanation.. It does make sense. One thing i want to know from above make file stuff is, How the flow of execution happens in make? I got this doubt because we are including dependency files first and then we are creating those .d files using -M* flags.  I am wondering how it includes those .d files. because for the first run there are no .d files. We created them and not placed 'include' directive after (instead we placed before) that. Could you please help me understanding this?

Comment: Make reads the entire makefile first, then after all makefiles, included makefiles, etc. are parsed and added to its internal structures, only then will it start to update targets.  So in almost all cases it doesn't matter in which order rules are defined.  Makefiles are _not_ like interpreted languages (shell, Python, etc.) where things are run as they are parsed.  The only times order matters are (a) choosing the default target, and (b) some very specific, uncommon forms of pattern rule matches.

Comment: The reason we don't care about the included files in the first run (when they don't exist) is that we already know we'll have to compile the source files, since there's no object file.  So whether or not there are any header files that are out of date is irrelevant.  For a full discussion see http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: Thanks For your help in understanding this  :)

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer please click the checkmark to others know that it's already answered.

Comment: I can't see it (only the author of the question can) but you seem to have found it!  Cheers.